# Prolog riddle solving

Tags: prolog, zebra-puzzle

**The statement :**

Four couples in all

Attended a costume ball.

2

The lady dressed as a cat

Arrived with her husband Matt.

3

Two couples were already there,

One man dressed like a bear.

4

First to arrive wasn't Vince,

But he got there before the Prince.

5

The witch (not Sue) is married to Chuck,

Who was dressed as Donald Duck.

6

Mary came in after Lou,

Both were there before Sue.

7

The Gipsy arrived before Ann,

Neither is wed to Batman.

8

If Snow White arrived after Tess,

Then how was each couple dressed?

**My code is here , but it returns false :**

```
sol(S):-
    S=[[1,L1,M1,LD1,MD1],
        [2,L2,M2,LD2,MD2],
        [3,L3,M3,LD3,MD3],
        [4,L4,M4,LD4,MD4]],
    member([_,_,matt,cat,_],S),
    member([ALR,_,_,_,bear],S),
    (ALR =:= 1 ; ALR =:= 2),
    not(member([1,_,vince,_,_],S)),
    member([VN,_,vince,_,_],S),
    member([PS,_,_,_,prince],S),
    VN < PS ,
    member([_,_,chuck,witch,donald],S),
    not(member([_,sue,_,witch,_],S)),
    member([MRY,mary,_,_,_],S),
    member([LOU,_,lou,_,_],S),
    member([SUE,sue,_,_,_],S),
    MRY > LOU,
    MRY < SUE,
    member([GPS,_,_,gipsy,_],S),
    member([ANN,ann,_,_,_],S),
    GPS < ANN ,
    not(member([_,_,_,gipsy,batman],S)),
    not(member([_,ann,_,_,batman],S)),
    member([SW,_,_,snowwhite,_],S),
    member([TS,tess,_,_,_],S),
    SW > TS ,
    perm([sue,mary,ann,tess],[L1,L2,L3,L4]),
    perm([matt,lou,vince,chuck],[M1,M2,M3,M4]),
    perm([cat,witch,gipsy,snowwhite],[LD1,LD2,LD3,LD4]),
    perm([donald,prince,batman,bear],[MD1,MD2,MD3,MD4]).




takeout(X,[X|R],R).
takeout(X,[F|R],[F|S]) :- takeout(X,R,S).

perm([],[]).
perm([X|Y],Z) :- perm(Y,W), takeout(X,Z,W).
```

Any solution ?

Comment: Have you done a `trace` to try to narrow this down any further, or have any other debugging results you can share? Your code doesn't have any facts stated, which is a little odd.

Comment: I think you're doing more complex than needed: why permuting the lists ?

Comment: Try moving all your `not(...)` goals to the very end of the predicate.

Answer (score 0):

You should move all your `not(...)` goals to the very end of the predicate.

`not(G)` means, "`G` is impossible to satisfy *right now*". When tried too early, with many still non-instantiated variables in the lists, it is in fact very often *possible* to satisfy a goal, and the whole `not(...)` call will fail right away.

Alternatively, delay the checking of the inequality on a variable until it is instantiated, e.g. in SWI Prolog with [`freeze/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=freeze/2) (as seen e.g. in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27591363/849891)).