# Filling a table in Prolog, given specific clues (Einstein riddle)

Tags: prolog, zebra-puzzle

There is a hypothetical table of five offices. Each office has a color, a department, a pc, a drink, a cellphone and a specific position from 1 to 5:

[image: The table is here]

I am trying to give the following clues to Prolog, so that it can fill the table correctly:

> 1. the man drinking milk is in office #3.
> 2. the man working in public relations ('pubrel') department is in
>      office #1.
> 3. the man from public relations department is next to the blue office.
> 4. the green office is on the right of the pink office.
> 5. the man in green office is drinking coffee.
> 6. the man in the yellow office has a blackberry cellphone, the yellow
>      office is next to the office of the man who has a windows7 pc.
> 7. the man working in the red office is from 'cs' department.
> 8. the man from 'ode' department has mac_pro pc.
> 9. the man from finance ('fin') department is drinking tea.
> 10. the man who has an iphone also has a mac_air pc.
> 11. the man with a nokia cellphone is next to the man who has a netbook
>        pc.
> 12. the man who has an android phone is drinking orange juice.
> 13. the man from supplies department has an ericsson phone.

I'm using

```
of(X,Y)
```

where X is an attribute of an office and Y is the position of said office.
For example:

```
of(color(yellow),1) -->office with yellow color is office #1
of(dept(cs),3) -->employee from cs department is in office #3
```

I define those clues as 'rules', that are all supposed to work at the same time.

```
rule1:-of(drink(milk),3),perm(drink(milk),3).
rule2:-of(dept(relations),1),perm(dept(relations),1).
rule3:-of(dept(relations),1),of(color(blue),2),perm(dept(relations),1),perm(color(blue),2).
rule3:-of(dept(relations),2),of(color(blue),3),perm(dept(relations),2),perm(color(blue),3).
rule3:-of(dept(relations),3),of(color(blue),4),perm(dept(relations),3),perm(color(blue),4).
rule3:-of(dept(relations),4),of(color(blue),5),perm(dept(relations),4),perm(color(blue),5).
rule4:-of(color(pink),1),of(color(green),2),perm(color(pink),1),perm(color(green),2).
rule4:-of(color(pink),2),of(color(green),3),perm(color(pink),2),perm(color(green),3).
rule4:-of(color(pink),3),of(color(green),4),perm(color(pink),3),perm(color(green),4).
rule4:-of(color(pink),4),of(color(green),5),perm(color(pink),4),perm(color(green),5).
rule5:-of(color(green),1),of(drink(coffee),1),perm(color(green),1),perm(drink(coffee),1).
rule5:-of(color(green),2),of(drink(coffee),2),perm(color(green),2),perm(drink(coffee),2).
rule5:-of(color(green),3),of(drink(coffee),3),perm(color(green),3),perm(drink(coffee),3).
rule5:-of(color(green),4),of(drink(coffee),4),perm(color(green),4),perm(drink(coffee),4).
rule5:-of(color(green),5),of(drink(coffee),5),perm(color(green),5),perm(drink(coffee),5).
rule6:-of(cell(blackberry),1),of(color(yellow),1),of(pc(win7),2),perm(cell(blackberry),1),perm(color(yellow),1),perm(pc(win7),2).
rule6:-of(cell(blackberry),2),of(color(yellow),2),of(pc(win7),3),perm(cell(blackberry),2),perm(color(yellow),2),perm(pc(win7),3).
rule6:-of(cell(blackberry),3),of(color(yellow),3),of(pc(win7),4),perm(cell(blackberry),3),perm(color(yellow),3),perm(pc(win7),4).
rule6:-of(cell(blackberry),4),of(color(yellow),4),of(pc(win7),5),perm(cell(blackberry),4),perm(color(yellow),4),perm(pc(win7),5).
rule6:-of(cell(blackberry),2),of(color(yellow),2),of(pc(win7),1),perm(cell(blackberry),2),perm(color(yellow),2),perm(pc(win7),1).
rule6:-of(cell(blackberry),3),of(color(yellow),3),of(pc(win7),2),perm(cell(blackberry),3),perm(color(yellow),3),perm(pc(win7),2).
rule6:-of(cell(blackberry),4),of(color(yellow),4),of(pc(win7),3),perm(cell(blackberry),4),perm(color(yellow),4),perm(pc(win7),3).
rule6:-of(cell(blackberry),5),of(color(yellow),5),of(pc(win7),4),perm(cell(blackberry),5),perm(color(yellow),5),perm(pc(win7),4).
rule7:-of(dept(cs),1),of(color(red),1),perm(dept(cs),1),perm(color(red),1).
rule7:-of(dept(cs),2),of(color(red),2),perm(dept(cs),2),perm(color(red),2).
rule7:-of(dept(cs),3),of(color(red),3),perm(dept(cs),3),perm(color(red),3).
rule7:-of(dept(cs),4),of(color(red),4),perm(dept(cs),4),perm(color(red),4).
rule7:-of(dept(cs),5),of(color(red),5),perm(dept(cs),5),perm(color(red),5).
rule8:-of(dept(ode),1),of(pc(mac_pro),1),perm(dept(ode),1),perm(pc(mac_pro),1).
rule8:-of(dept(ode),2),of(pc(mac_pro),2),perm(dept(ode),2),perm(pc(mac_pro),2).
rule8:-of(dept(ode),3),of(pc(mac_pro),3),perm(dept(ode),3),perm(pc(mac_pro),3).
rule8:-of(dept(ode),4),of(pc(mac_pro),4),perm(dept(ode),4),perm(pc(mac_pro),4).
rule8:-of(dept(ode),5),of(pc(mac_pro),5),perm(dept(ode),5),perm(pc(mac_pro),5).
rule9:-of(dept(fin),1),of(drink(tea),1),perm(dept(fin),1),perm(drink(tea),1).
rule9:-of(dept(fin),2),of(drink(tea),2),perm(dept(fin),2),perm(drink(tea),2).
rule9:-of(dept(fin),3),of(drink(tea),3),perm(dept(fin),3),perm(drink(tea),3).
rule9:-of(dept(fin),4),of(drink(tea),4),perm(dept(fin),4),perm(drink(tea),4).
rule9:-of(dept(fin),5),of(drink(tea),5),perm(dept(fin),5),perm(drink(tea),5).
rule10:-of(cell(iphone),1),of(pc(mac_air),1),perm(cell(iphone),1),perm(pc(mac_air),1).
rule10:-of(cell(iphone),2),of(pc(mac_air),2),perm(cell(iphone),2),perm(pc(mac_air),2).
rule10:-of(cell(iphone),3),of(pc(mac_air),3),perm(cell(iphone),3),perm(pc(mac_air),3).
rule10:-of(cell(iphone),4),of(pc(mac_air),4),perm(cell(iphone),4),perm(pc(mac_air),4).
rule10:-of(cell(iphone),5),of(pc(mac_air),5),perm(cell(iphone),5),perm(pc(mac_air),5).
rule11:-of(cell(nokia),1),of(pc(netbook),2),perm(cell(nokia),1),perm(pc(netbook),2).
rule11:-of(cell(nokia),2),of(pc(netbook),3),perm(cell(nokia),2),perm(pc(netbook),3).
rule11:-of(cell(nokia),3),of(pc(netbook),4),perm(cell(nokia),3),perm(pc(netbook),4).
rule11:-of(cell(nokia),4),of(pc(netbook),5),perm(cell(nokia),4),perm(pc(netbook),5).
rule11:-of(cell(nokia),2),of(pc(netbook),1),perm(cell(nokia),2),perm(pc(netbook),1).
rule11:-of(cell(nokia),3),of(pc(netbook),2),perm(cell(nokia),3),perm(pc(netbook),2).
rule11:-of(cell(nokia),4),of(pc(netbook),3),perm(cell(nokia),4),perm(pc(netbook),3).
rule11:-of(cell(nokia),5),of(pc(netbook),4),perm(cell(nokia),5),perm(pc(netbook),4).
rule12:-of(cell(android),1),of(drink(orangejuice),1),perm(cell(android),1),perm(drink(orangejuice),1).
rule12:-of(cell(android),2),of(drink(orangejuice),2),perm(cell(android),2),perm(drink(orangejuice),2).
rule12:-of(cell(android),3),of(drink(orangejuice),3),perm(cell(android),3),perm(drink(orangejuice),3).
rule12:-of(cell(android),4),of(drink(orangejuice),4),perm(cell(android),4),perm(drink(orangejuice),4).
rule12:-of(cell(android),5),of(drink(orangejuice),5),perm(cell(android),5),perm(drink(orangejuice),5).
rule13:-of(dept(supplies),1),of(cell(ericsson),1),perm(dept(supplies),1),perm(cell(ericsson),1).
rule13:-of(dept(supplies),2),of(cell(ericsson),2),perm(dept(supplies),2),perm(cell(ericsson),2).
rule13:-of(dept(supplies),3),of(cell(ericsson),3),perm(dept(supplies),3),perm(cell(ericsson),3).
rule13:-of(dept(supplies),4),of(cell(ericsson),4),perm(dept(supplies),4),perm(cell(ericsson),4).
rule13:-of(dept(supplies),5),of(cell(ericsson),5),perm(dept(supplies),5),perm(cell(ericsson),5).
```

and then feed them all to a predicate 'office' that is supposed to be true if they can all apply together, so that the table is formed correctly.

```
office:-rule1,rule2,rule3,rule4...
```

I define `perm(X,Y)` as a term that becomes true when the attribute `X` is allowed to capture the specific spot `Y`, meaning that `X` has not captured another one and is therefore permitted.

```
perm(X,1):-not(of(X,2)),not(of(X,3)),not(of(X,4)),not(of(X,5)).
perm(X,2):-not(of(X,1)),not(of(X,3)),not(of(X,4)),not(of(X,5)).
perm(X,3):-....
```

And finally, `of(X,Y)` is supposed to become true if the spot `Y` is not already taken by another `X`.
For example, `of(color(red),3)` is supposed to be true if no other color has captured spot 3.

```
of(color(red),Y):-not(of(color(green),Y)),not(of(color(pink),Y)),
        not(of(color(blue),Y)),not(of(color(yellow),Y)).
of(color(green),Y):-not(of(color(red),Y)),not(of(color(pink),Y)),
        not(of(color(blue),Y)),not(of(color(yellow),Y)).
...
of(dept(cs),Y):-not(of(dept(ode),Y)),not(of(dept(supplies),Y)),
        not(of(dept(fin),Y)),not(of(dept(relations),Y)).
of(dept(ode),Y):-not(of(dept(cs),Y)),not(of(dept(supplies),Y)),
        not(of(dept(fin),Y)),not(of(dept(relations),Y)).
...
```

So, `perm(X,Y)` and `of(X,Y)` are supposed to be true at the same time in each rule.

And it's not working, probably because it does have anything concrete to start with. It does not know when

```
not(of(color(green),1))
```

will be true. But I'm stuck and can't think of a way to define something specific to start with. Can anyone help on how to make it work?

Comment: Whitespace is non-fatal in Prolog programs. :) And I would recommend you use `\+/1` instead of `not/1` because the former is ISO and the latter is not. Besides that, this is kind of an odd way to approach the program. I will come back in a few hours and elaborate if nobody else has by then.

Comment: cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252656/einsteins-riddle-prolog/20092493#20092493

Comment: @WillNess Thank you! I'm also trying to fix my approach though. :)

Comment: @DanielLyons Thanks, I would appreciate it! Would you say it's an impractical way?

Comment: @WillNess No, I already have the clues, they are given as input. The desired output the predicate office making sure that all the rules can work at the same time, forming the table. The initial request is "find who is drinking water and who has windowsxp", but I guess it will be easy to get them if I can just make all the rules work together.

Comment: @WillNess Pretty much, yes. I included all of the clues now. As I said, the original question is "who is drinking water and who has a windowsxp pc". But I solved it on my own and included those missing clues in my code (as rules) as well, and now I'm trying to make prolog complete the table correctly, based on the clues.

Comment: To put it more specifically, my desired output is the predicate office being true if the all the rules can be applied at the same time. If a rule is contradictory, it should be false, because in that case they don't work altogether.

Comment: @WillNess I included everything with the right numbering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach won't ever work, because it has unbounded recursion built-in. Its logic is circular. It never stops. Limiting ourselves to only two colors, you definitions are

```
of(color(red),Y):- not(of(color(green),Y)).
of(color(green),Y):- not(of(color(red),Y)).
```

You only ever build your knowledge in the negative. You should hold a positive knowledge somewhere, in some fashion: "the office 1 is pink", not "the office 1 is not green nor yellow etc".  <sup>(1)</sup>

You only have five colors at your disposal; if it's none of the four, it is by necessity the fifth.

`perm` seems thus completely superfluous. If you now *get* back from your predicate the positive knowledge about an office's color, then if it's red, it's red.

And "next-to" means, (e.g. for *"the man from public relations department is next to the blue office."*),

```
of(dept(pubrel),X), of(color(blue),Y),
of(position(I),X), of(position(J),Y), 1 is abs (I-J).
```

`of` should be coded so that it records the knowledge somehow. There's plenty examples in the linked answers or under the tag [zebra-puzzle](/questions/tagged/zebra-puzzle) on how to achieve that.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> (*update:*) on the other hand, you could write

```
    of(Rec1,color(not_green_nor_yellow),Y,RecN):- 
        not_of(Rec1,color(green),Y,Rec2),
        not_of(Rec2,color(yellow),Y,RecN).
```

the idea is to start with full possibilities recorded, and then have them actually removed one by one from that record (by `not_of/4` predicate) until there is strictly one possibility left (like Sudoku). Maybe this is what you had in mind. You'd still maintain your positive knowledge (even while expressing it negatively), which is a list of all currently possible choices for each office.

So under one paradigm we add choices (so adding both yellow and green color to same office is a contradiction - an office can only have one color), and under the other we remove them (removing both yellow and green is perfectly fine unless this empties the list of the remaining choices for that office - an office must have some color, one color).

Comment: You are right, I see it now... Thank you for your help! :)