# Is there a way to extend Einstein's Riddle in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, zebra-puzzle

First off, thank you for dropping by my question. On to the question, I have been working on a Prolog code to model Einstein's riddle. I think it's a pretty elegant solution, it's basically a list of tuples with certain fields such as house color, pet, nationality etc. I have the list modeled and the hints are there as well, but I'm having trouble trying to model the question.

The thing is, I didn't want to stick to just a simple question of "Who *owns* the *fish*?". I wanted to model a harder question. For example: "What *pet* does the person who lives in the house which is *to the right* of the *red* house *own*?". It appears to be a simple check for the index `i` in the list which has the tuple with the color `red`, and return the field `pet` of the tuple at the index `i+1` in the list, but my experience with Prolog is pretty limited (it is virtually my first time using it) and I'm not really sure how to implement it. I'll provide the code I have below. I appreciate all answers. Thank you.

```
persoane(0, []) :- ! .
persoane(N, [(_Men, _Color, _Drink, _Smoke, _Animal)|T]) :- N1 is N-1, persoane(N1,T) .

persoana(1, [H|_], H) :- ! .
persoana(N, [_|T], R) :- N1 is N-1, persoana(N1, T, R)

% Function that tests if A is to the right of B (will be used in the final question)
right(A, B, List) :- nextto(B, A, List).

% The Brit lives in the red house
hint1([(brit, red, _, _, _)|_]) .
hint1([_|T]) :- hint1(T) .

% The Swede keeps dogs as pets
hint2([(swede, _, _, _, dog)|_]) .
hint2([_|T]) :- hint2(T) .

% The Dane drinks tea
hint3([(dane, _, tea, _, _)|_]) .
hint3([_|T]) :- hint3(T) .

% The green house is on the left of the white house
hint4([(_, green, _, _, _,),(_, white, _, _, _)|_]) .
hint4([_|T]) :- hint4(T) .

% The green house owner drinks coffee
hint5([(_, green, cofee, _, _)|_]) .
hint5([_|T]) :- hint5(T) .

% The person who smokes Pall Mall rears birds
hint6([(_, _, _, pallmall, bird)|_]) .
hint6([_|T]) :- hint6(T) .

% The owner of the yellow house smokes Dunhill
hint7([(_, yellow, _, dunhill, _)|_]) .
hint7([_|T]) :- hint7(T) .

% The man living in the center house drinks milk
hint8(persoane) :- persoana(3, persoane, (_, _, milk, _, _)) .

% The Norwegian lives in the first house
hint9(persoane) :- persoana(1, persoane, (norwegian, _, _, _, _)) .

% The man who smokes Blends lives next to the one who keeps cats
hint10([(_, _, _, blend, _),(_, _, _, _, cat)|_]) .
hint10([(_, _, _, _, cat),(_, _, _, blend, _)|_]) .
hint10([_|T]) :- hint10(T) .

% The man who keeps horses lives next to the man who smokes Dunhill
hint11([(_, _, _, dunhill, _),(_, _, _, _, horse)|_]) .
hint11([(_, _, _, _, horse),(_, _, _, dunhill, _)|_]) .
hint11([_|T]) :- hint11(T) .

% The owner who smokes BlueMaster drinks beer
hint12([(_, _, beer, bluemaster, _)|_]) .
hint12([_|T]) :- hint12(T) .

% The German smokes Prince
hint13([(german, _, _, prince, _)|_]) .
hint13([_|T]) :- hint13(T) .

% The Norwegian lives next to the blue house
hint14([(norwegian, _, _, _, _),(_, blue, _, _, _)|_]) .
hint14([(_, blue, _, _, _),(norwegian, _, _, _, _)|_]) .
hint14([_|T]) :- hint14(T) .

% The man who smokes Blend has a neighbour who drinks water
hint15([(_, _, _, blend, _),(_, _, water, _, _)|_]) .
hint15([(_, _, water, _, _),(_, _, _, blend, _)|_]) .
hint15([_|T]) :- hint15(T) .

% The question: What pet does the man who lives to the right of the red house have ?
% question (right((_, _, _, _, _), (_, red, _, _, _), persoane)) .
question([(_, red, _, _, _),()])
question([_|T]) :- question(T) .

solution(persoane) :-
   persoana(5, persoane),
   hint1(persoane),
   hint2(persoane),
   hint3(persoane),
   hint4(persoane),
   hint5(persoane),
   hint6(persoane),
   hint7(persoane),
   hint8(persoane),
   hint9(persoane),
   hint10(persoane),
   hint11(persoane),
   hint12(persoane),
   hint13(persoane),
   hint14(persoane),
   hint15(persoane),
   question(persoane) .
```

Comment: What results were you expecting from queries such as `persoane(2,X)`?

Comment: (1,2,3,4,5) is not a "tuple". It's short for `','(1,','(2,','(3,','(4,5))))`. (Use `write_canonical/1` to see this). I think you want to use regular lists, e.g. `[1,2,3,4,5]`. Your system might have a predicate `nth0/3` or `nth1/3` --- take a look at how it's implemented.

Comment: I'm pretty sure persoane(2,X) would just return the information on the "tuple" at index 2, something like (dane, blue, tea, blend, horse) since that's the second house in the solution on Einstein's Riddle. I think it's perfectly fine if no particular information could be extracted from such "tuples", like the pet or the color of the house. I turned to Stackoverflow because I had no ideas left on how to deal with this. I remember checking on things like "Zebra problem" but most of them didn't deal with more advanced questions like the one I mentioned in the quesiton.

Comment: I will look into your suggestions though, perhaps I can find something.

Comment: I managed to do something on this riddle, the code can be found here [link](https://ghostbin.co/paste/uyqh6). I wonder if there is a way to "query" this data to output the pet of the owner of the house on the right of the red house.

Comment: In Prolog, variables start with a capital letter.

Try changing your last predicate to:
```
solution(Persoane) :-
   persoana(5, Persoane),
   hint1(Persoane),
   hint2(Persoane),
      ...
   hint15(Persoane),
   question(Persoane) .
```

Comment: This is a well known problem. Try searching for "Zebra problem" for many more questions and answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can access positionally into a list like this:

```
index(one,   [One, _, _, _, _],   One).
index(two,   [_, Two, _, _, _],   Two).
index(three, [_, _, Three, _, _], Three).
index(four,  [_, _, _, Four, _],  Four).
index(five(, [_, _, _, _, Five],  Five).
```

You can also define `next_to` in a similar way:

```
next_to(List, A, B) :- left_right(List, A, B).
next_to(List, A, B) :- right_left(List, A, B).
right_left(List, A, B) :- left_right(List, B, A).
left_right([A,B,_,_,_], A,B).
left_right([_,A,B,_,_], A,B).
left_right([_,_,A,B,_], A,B).
left_right([_,_,_,A,B], A,B).
```

There are more generic solutions that work for any length of list (left as an exercise).

Answer (score 1):

We can code it *top-down style*. This means using some made-up predicates and implementing them later, according to how we've just used them:

```ml
puzzle( P, Pet ) :- length( P, _ ),
    clue( P, [house-red , nation-brit ] ),    % (* 1. The Brit lives in red house *)
    clue( P, [keeps-dogs, nation-swede] ),    % (* 2. The Swede has dogs as pets  *)
    clue( P, [drinks-tea, nation-dane ] ),                      % (* 3. .....  *)
    clue( P,  left_of, [[house -red   ], [house -white  ]] ),   % (* 4. .....  *)
    clue( P, [house-green,  drinks-coffee  ] ),                 % (*  .......  *)
    clue( P, [keeps-birds,  smokes-pallmall] ),                   
    clue( P, [house-yellow, smokes-dunhill ] ),                   
    clue( P,  center,  [[drinks-milk  ]                  ] ),     
    clue( P,  first,   [[nation-norse ]                  ] ),     
    clue( P,  next_to, [[smokes-blends], [keeps -cats   ]] ),     
    clue( P,  next_to, [[keeps -horses], [smokes-dunhill]] ),     
    clue( P, [smokes-bluemaster, drinks-beer  ] ),                
    clue( P, [nation-german    , smokes-prince] ),
    clue( P,  next_to, [[nation-norse ], [house -blue   ]] ),
    clue( P,  next_to, [[smokes-blends], [drinks-water  ]] ),
    %% (* Who has the zebra ? *)
    clue( P, [keeps-zebra, nation- _Who] ),
    %% (* What pet the man owns who lives to the right of the red house? *)
    clue( P, right_of, [[keeps-Pet   ], [house -red    ]] ),
    maplist( length, P, _ ).

clue( P, AS ) :- member( H, P ), attrs( H, AS ).
clue( P, C, ASs ) :- G =.. [ C, P | ASs], G.

left_of(  P, AS1, AS2 ) :- append( _, [H1, H2 | _], P ),
                                           attrs( H1, AS1 ),
                                           attrs( H2, AS2 ).
next_to(  P, AS1, AS2 ) :- left_of( P, AS1, AS2 ) ; right_of( P, AS1, AS2 ).
right_of( P, AS1, AS2 ) :- left_of( P, AS2, AS1 ).
center(   P,      AS  ) :- middle( P, H ), attrs( H , AS  ).
first(  [H | _],  AS  ) :-                 attrs( H , AS  ).
middle( [H    ], H ).
middle( [_ | R], H ) :- append( X, [_], R ), middle( X, H ).
```

What's left is to define [`attrs/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252656/einsteins-riddle-prolog/20092493#20092493), implementing *extensible records* of sorts, and using them as a rudimentary object system so that the program "learns" about the properties of the *objects* involved (here, *people*) just from their *use* -- instead of the human programmer infusing *their* understanding by fixing  a specific representation of said objects in the program a priori (as e.g. 5-tuples, etc.):

```ml
attr( House, Attr-Value) :-         % progressively instantiated
    memberchk( Attr-X, House),      % unique attribute names
    X = Value.                      

attrs( H, AS) :- maplist( attr(H),AS ).
```

The final goal `maplist( length, P, _ )` "freezes" those extensible records  (implemented as open-ended lists, for simplicity) by putting the `[]` into their sentinels (try e.g. `X = [1, 2 | _], length( X, _ )` to see what it does).

The goal `length( P, _ )` right at the start provides for the *iterative deepening* approach. Without it the predicate loops, unfortunately.

For nice printout we can run it through

```ml
test :- puzzle( P, Pet ), 
        maplist( sort, P, PS ), maplist( writeln, PS ), nl, 
        writeln( Pet ).
```

producing the output (manually aligned)

```ml
62 ?- time( (test, !) ).
[drinks-water, house-yellow,keeps-cats,  nation-norse, smokes-dunhill   ]
[drinks-tea,   house-blue,  keeps-horses,nation-dane,  smokes-blends    ]
[drinks-milk,  house-red,   keeps-birds, nation-brit,  smokes-pallmall  ]
[drinks-beer,  house-white, keeps-dogs,  nation-swede, smokes-bluemaster]
[drinks-coffee,house-green, keeps-zebra, nation-german,smokes-prince    ]

dogs
% 167,950 inferences, 0.047 CPU in 0.050 seconds (94% CPU, 3588652 Lips)
true.
```