# Prolog - deleting pairs with the same first value from list

Tags: list, prolog

i have list of objects like this

```
list([obj(x,y),obj(x,z),obj(a,b),obj(b,c)]).
```

and i would like to remove those elements that share the same first value, so i can work with the modified list. In this case the final list would look like this

```
list([obj(a,b),obj(b,c)]
```

Could anyone help please? I am really struggling with this one.

Comment: Soo ... retain the object with the lowest index?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61096861/849891) out. :)

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the tests!

```
% Testing

:- begin_tests(collapse).   

test(one)   :- collapse([],[]).
test(two)   :- collapse([obj(a,b)],[obj(a,b)]).
test(three) :- collapse([obj(a,b),obj(b,c)],
                        [obj(a,b),obj(b,c)]).                        
test(four)  :- collapse([obj(a,b),obj(a,c),obj(b,j)],
                        [obj(b,j)]).
test(five)  :- collapse([obj(a,b),obj(a,c),obj(b,j),obj(a,x),obj(b,y)],
                        []).
test(six)   :- collapse([obj(a,b),obj(a,c),obj(b,j),obj(b,y),obj(c,x)],
                        [obj(c,x)]).

:- end_tests(collapse).

rt :- run_tests(collapse).
```

Then code:

```
% This is called

collapse(Lin,Lout) :- collapse(Lin,[],Lout).

/*
 * Helper predicate:
 * collapse(List_over_which_we_recur_getting_smaller,
 *          Elements_which_we_have_already_seen,
 *          List_which_collects_the_result_going_down,
 *          List_which_collects_the_result_coming_up).
 */

collapse([],_Filter,[]).  % base case, kick a [] upwards; don't care about Filter

collapse([obj(A,_)|Objs],Filter,Lup) :- 
   (member(obj(A,_),Objs);member(obj(A,_),Filter)),     % Does the obj(A,_) appear elsewhere (in Filter or Objs)?
   !,                                                   % Commit to this execution path where obj(A,_) is not unique
   (member(obj(A,_),Filter)                             % Slight improvement: add obj(A,_) to "Filter" only it it's not yet in there
       -> NewFilter = Filter
       ;  NewFilter = [obj(A,_)|Filter]),
   collapse(Objs,NewFilter,Lup).                        % Do not retain obj(A,_)

collapse([obj(A,X)|Objs],Filter,Lup) :- 
   \+(member(obj(A,_),Objs);member(obj(A,_),Filter)),   % Does the obj(A,_) appear elsewhere (in Seen or ToSee)?
   !,                                                   % Commit to this execution path where obj(A,_) IS unique   
   collapse(Objs,Filter,Ltmp),                          % Filtering the rest of Objs, which defines Ltmp      
   Lup = [obj(A,X)|Ltmp].                               % DO retain object on the way up, correctly ordering result.
```

Okay, so:

```
?- rt.
% PL-Unit: collapse ...... done
% All 6 tests passed
true.
```

Comment: The [Coding Guidelines for Prolog](https://arxiv.org/abs/0911.2899) say one should avoid comments to the right but they are really useful; in fact, there should be dedicated editor support for them.

Comment: The Scheme/Lisp coding style guidelines demand no extra spacing inside the lines of code (and Prolog's probably does too), but code is a ***2D*** medium, and [vertical](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27804489/849891) [alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60877178/849891) [helps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11551001/849891), sometimes immensely. :) (including the links here just for the illustration.)

Answer (score 1):

Solving this problem efficiently is not trivial for a beginner. Assuming that the elements of the list are ground, we can start by noticing that sorting the list will cluster together all elements that shared the first argument in the `obj/2` compound term. For example:

```
| ?- sort([obj(x,y),obj(x,z),obj(a,b),obj(b,c)], S).
S = [obj(a, b), obj(b, c), obj(x, y), obj(x, z)]
yes
```

The `sort/2` is a standard built-in predicate. Any decent Prolog system should implement it with complexity O(n*log(n)). After sorting, we can walk the list, which we can so in O(n) to filter it:

```
filter(List, Filtered) :-
    sort(List, Sorted),
    walk(Sorted, Filtered).

walk([], []).
walk([obj(X,Y)| Sorted], Filtered) :-
    walk(Sorted, X, obj(X,Y), Filtered).

walk([], _, Element, [Element]).
walk([obj(X,_)| Sorted], X, _, Filtered) :-
    !,
    delete(Sorted, X, Rest),
    walk(Rest, Filtered).
walk([obj(X,Y)| Sorted], _, Element, [Element| Filtered]) :-
    walk(Sorted, X, obj(X,Y), Filtered).

delete([], _, []).
delete([obj(X,_)| Sorted], X, Rest) :-
    !,
    delete(Sorted, X, Rest).
delete(Rest, _, Rest).
```

Sample call:

```
| ?- filter([obj(x,y),obj(x,z),obj(a,b),obj(b,c)], Filtered).
Filtered = [obj(a, b), obj(b, c)]
yes
```

Looks good but we should do more comprehensive testing. We can define a property that all the `filter/2` predicate solutions must satisfy:

```
property(List, Filtered) :-
    filter(List, Filtered),
    % all elements of the output list must
    % be in input list
    forall(
        member(X, Filtered),
        member(X, List)
    ),
    % no two elements in the output list
    % should share the first argument
    \+ (
        select(obj(X,_), Filtered, Rest),
        member(obj(X,_), Rest)
    ),
    % all elements in the input list whose
    % first argument is not repeated must
    % be in the output list
    \+ (
        select(obj(X,Y), List, Rest),
        \+ member(obj(X,_), Rest),
        \+ member(obj(X,Y), Filtered)
    ).
```

We can now use a *property-based testing* implementation such as Logtalk's [`lgtunit`](https://logtalk3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/devtools/lgtunit.html#quickcheck) QuickCheck implementation. But there's a catch. Property-based testing requires that we be able to generate lists with `obj/2` elements. The solution, we cheat! First we do a **syntactic** transformation from `obj(X,Y)` to `X-Y`. This transformation doesn't change the semantics of the predicate being tested:

```
filter(List, Filtered) :-
    sort(List, Sorted),
    walk(Sorted, Filtered).

walk([], []).
walk([X-Y| Sorted], Filtered) :-
    walk(Sorted, X, X-Y, Filtered).

walk([], _, Element, [Element]).
walk([X-_| Sorted], X, _, Filtered) :-
    !,
    delete(Sorted, X, Rest),
    walk(Rest, Filtered).
walk([X-Y| Sorted], _, Element, [Element| Filtered]) :-
    walk(Sorted, X, X-Y, Filtered).

delete([], _, []).
delete([X-_| Sorted], X, Rest) :-
    !,
    delete(Sorted, X, Rest).
delete(Rest, _, Rest).
```

We apply the same syntactic transformation to the `property/2` predicate:

```
property(List, Filtered) :-
    filter(List, Filtered),
    % all elements of the output list must
    % be in input list
    forall(
        member(X, Filtered),
        member(X, List)
    ),
    % no two elements in the output list
    % should share the first argument
    \+ (
        select(X-_, Filtered, Rest),
        member(X-_, Rest)
    ),
    % all elements in the input list whose
    % first argument is not repeated must
    % be in the output list
    \+ (
        select(X-Y, List, Rest),
        \+ member(X-_, Rest),
        \+ member(X-Y, Filtered)
    ).
```

We can now test using the goal:

```
| ?- lgtunit::quick_check(
         property(
             +list(pair(char,char)),
             -list(pair(char,char))
         )
     ).
% 100 random tests passed
% starting seed: seed(25256,26643,1563)
yes
```

Note: in the definition of the `property/2` predicate, we assume that the de facto standard `member/2` and `select/3` list predicates are available in `user` (i.e. at the top-level  interpreter). If that's not the case, prefix their calls with `list::`.

Comment: I hope this goes into the Manual.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer Already there: https://logtalk3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/devtools/lgtunit.html#quickcheck

Comment: @DavidTonhofer Expanded this answer in the following blog post: https://logtalk.org/2020/04/10/evolving-from-manually-written-tests.html

Comment: Thanks Paulo. I hope to try this soon-ish.