# Prolog Shark Nationality

Tags: prolog, zebra-puzzle

I need to solve this problem with a Prolog code in SWISH:

> "
> In a quiet street located in a galaxy far, far away, there are five houses, each of a different color. In each house lives a person of a different nationality. Each of the five people drinks a different beverage, has a different type of fish in their aquarium, and has a different pet. Consider the following conditions:
> a. The Norwegian lives in the first house.
> b. The Englishman lives in the red house.
> c. The green house is immediately to the left of the white house.
> d. The Danish person drinks tea.
> e. The person who drinks coffee lives in the green house.
> f. The person who drinks milk lives in the third house.
> g. The Swede has a dog as a pet.
> h. The Norwegian lives next to the blue house.
> i. The German drinks beer.
> j. The Brazilian lives in the yellow house.
> k. The cat lives in the house next to the one where they drink water.
> l. Betta fish live in the house next to the one where they drink tea.
> m. The yellow house is next to the house where betta fish live.
>
> Your task will be, using Prolog, to determine who has a shark in their aquarium."

I tried this:

```
color(House, Color) :-
    member(House-Color, [
        house1-red,
        house2-green,
        house3-white,
        house4-yellow,
        house5-blue
    ]).

nationality(Person, Nationality) :-
    member(Person-Nationality, [
        house1-norwegian,
        house2-english,
        house3-danish,
        house4-german,
        house5-brazilian
    ]).

drink(Person, Beverage) :-
    member(Person-Beverage, [
        house1-water,
        house2-coffee,
        house3-milk,
        house4-beer,
        house5-tea
    ]).

fish(House, Fish) :-
    member(House-Fish, [
        house1-cat,
        house2-bird,
        house3-betta_fish,
        house4-dog,
        house5-shark
    ]).

next_to(X, Y, List) :- 
    nextto(X, Y, List); 
    nextto(Y, X, List).

member(X, [X | _]).
member(X, [_ | Rest]) :- member(X, Rest).

solve(Nationality) :-
    Houses = [
        house(_, _, _, _, _),
        house(_, _, _, _, _),
        house(_, _, _, _, _),
        house(_, _, _, _, _),
        house(_, _, _, _, _)
    ],
    
    member(house(norwegian, _, _, _, _), Houses),
    
    member(house(_, red, _, _, _), Houses),
    
    next_to(house(_, green, _, _, _), house(_, white, _, _, _), Houses),
    
    member(house(danish, _, tea, _, _), Houses),
    
    member(house(_, green, coffee, _, _), Houses),
    
    Houses = [_, _, house(_, _, milk, _, _), _, _],
    
    member(house(swede, _, _, dog, _), Houses),
    
    next_to(house(norwegian, _, _, _, _), house(_, blue, _, _, _), Houses),
    
    member(house(german, _, beer, _, _), Houses),
    
    member(house(brazilian, yellow, _, _, _), Houses),
    
    next_to(house(_, _, _, _, cat), house(_, _, water, _, _), Houses),
    
    next_to(house(_, _, _, _, betta_fish), house(_, _, tea, _, _), Houses),
    
    next_to(house(_, yellow, _, _, _), house(_, _, _, _, betta_fish), Houses),

    member(house(_, _, _, shark, _), Houses),

    (member(house(_, _, _, cat, _), Houses); member(house(_, _, _, dog, _), Houses)),

    member(house(Nationality, _, _, _, shark), Houses).

?- solve(Nationality).
```

I think the answer is German, but the code gives me Brazilian

Comment: Cats and dogs and sharks aren't fish, and you have them in the wrong position in some of your house terms; `house(_, _, _, _, cat)` vs. `house(_, _, _, cat, _)`

Comment: see e.g. if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60809926/is-there-a-way-to-extend-einsteins-riddle-in-prolog/60877178#60877178) or any of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bzebra-puzzle%5D+user%3A849891) helps.